# Paypal sandbox stopped working

Tags: paypal

I have a website that is currently using Paypal. The staging version of this site is linked to the Paypal sandbox, and used to work perfectly until i recently noticed that it was not working anymore. I updated the Paypal_Merchant_SDK.dll to the most recent version using NuGet, and now i'm being thrown this message:

> BC30456: 'GetProperty' is not a member of 'PayPal.Manager.ConfigManager'.
>
> Dim paypalUrl As String = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperty("paypalUrl").ToString()

I'm not sure what the previous version of the DLL was, but it was implemented some 3 or 4 years ago, so it was obviously dated. Do i need to completely redo all my code, or are there simple adjustments that will make this work properly again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if it relates to your case but Paypal have recently made changes requiring websites -in certain instances such as IPN- that carry transactions with them to be `HTTPS`.

Comment: Why are you using 3-4 year old code on a sandbox?

Comment: The website was produced 3/4 years ago, and the sandbox was implemented on the staging while in development at that same time. Now that i came across this issue, i updated it. That is why i was using outdated code. Im using express checkout and both the endpoint and the paypalUrl are HTTPS URLs

Comment: My comment was meaning that the website that talks to Paypal -- your website -- may need to be HTTPS, but this may be less likely with Express Checkout. Paypal have various code on gitHub which is probably their most updo date codes, worth searching for. But as a whole their (Paypals) documentation is appauling.

Comment: This hasn't been updated for a few years but here is [Paypal Express Checkout on GitHub](https://github.com/romaonthego/paypal-express-checkout)

Comment: [Also an example case](https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Express-Checkout-example)